# Reverse a linked list using recursion technique in C

Tags: c, algorithm

I have the following C code which returns the reverse of a linked list.

Though it reverses the linked list, I never get the head of the reversed linked list because the `restofElements` node is getting overwritten.

```
S *reverseRecursive(S *headref) {
    S *firstElement   = NULL;
    S *restOfElements = NULL;

    if (headref==NULL) {
        return ;
    }

    firstElement = headref;
    restOfElements = headref->next;

    if (restOfElements == NULL)
        return headref;   

    reverseRecursive(restOfElements);    
    firstElement->next->next  = firstElement;
    firstElement->next  = NULL;          
    headref = restOfElements; 

    return headref; 
}
```

How can I get the head of the reversed linked list node returned to the calling program?

Comment: Shoot.  You have to have something receiving the return from the recursive call. I'm sure that's a core problem with your code.

Comment: BTW: Suggest changing `return ;`  to `return NULL;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the head pointer, you must pass it by reference (as a pointer). The prototype should be modified to receive the head as S **.

```
S *reverseRecursive(S **headref);
```

Comment: @Jim He's returning the pointer, right. But eyalm's suggestion still solves the problem. The return-statements are not needed - passing headref as reference will do the trick.

Comment: @krrishna The problem is, you are returning the restOfElements of the first element. Meaning you will always receive the originally 2nd element in return. You can define your function as 'S* reverseRecursive(S*& headref)' or even as 'void reverseRecursive(S*& headref)'.

Comment: @eyalm  I'm not disputing you, but krrishna needs to decide how he wants to do the recursion.  If he passes as a reference, then he should have a void function as sebi indicates.

Answer (score 1):

The head of the reversed list is equal to the head of the reversed List starting with `restOfElements` (because the original `headref` has to become tha last element of the reversed list). So storing the result of the recussive call should do (as Jim has already suggested in his comment):

```
...
headref = reverseRecursive(restOfElements);  
firstElement->next->next  = firstElement;
firstElement->next  = NULL;          
/* headref = restOfElements; that's wrong */    
return headref;
```

Comment: I agree that this segment is problematic because the ->next->next could run one off the rails.

Comment: @Jim, I don't think because before the part of the code I've copied, there is a check `if( restOfElements == NULL )...` and `restOfElements ==  headref->next == firstELement->next`

Comment: @Jim firstElement->next is always a not-null pointer, it's checked before, so there will be no problem with that I think.

Answer (score 1):

Probably closer.

```
S *reverseRecursive(S *headref)
 {
  S *firstElement   = NULL;
  S *restOfElements = NULL;
  S *new_head = NULL;
  if (headref==NULL)
    {
    return ;
    }
  firstElement = headref;
  restOfElements = headref->next;
  if (restOfElements == NULL)
       return headref;   
  new_head = reverseRecursive(restOfElements); 
  restOfElements->next = new_head;           
  return restOfElements;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone. I have modified it little bit and it works now. Let me know your comments.
new_head is a global variable.

```
S *reverseRecursive(S *headref)
 {
  S *firstElement   = NULL;
  S *restOfElements = NULL;

  if (headref==NULL)
    {
    return ;
    }
    firstElement = headref;


   if (headref->next == NULL)
      return headref;   
   else
    restOfElements = headref->next;


   reverseRecursive(restOfElements);

   firstElement->next->next  = firstElement;

   firstElement->next  = NULL;          

   if(new_head == NULL ) //just dont take it ervery time
      new_head = restOfElements;

   return new_head; 

  }
```

Comment: I'm really glad you got it working.  Good for you!  Recursion can be tricky.  You might get some flak about new_head being a global var.  If you want to avoid that, you can add it as a second input parameter (init to NULL) and just carry it along that way.  But great that you got something working.  Congrats!

Comment: I'm surprised this compiles and you should turn up the compiler warning level. Your function is defined as returning `S*` but you have a bare `return;` statement that returns nothing and a recursive call that discards the returned value.

Comment: If he passed in a NULL pointer, I don't think it would work.  (Doesn't a blank return return the top of the stack or something?).  The other problems seem to cancel each other out....

Answer (score 1):

$ gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra reverse.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct list {
  struct list* next;
  int data;
} S;

void print_list(S* list) {
  if (list == NULL) { printf("NULL\n"); return; }
  printf("%d ", list->data);
  print_list(list->next);
}

S* reverse_aux(S* list, S* tail) {
  // invalid arg
  if (list == NULL) { return NULL; }

  // base case
  if (list->next == NULL) {
    list->next = tail;
    return list;
  }

  // general case
  S* tmp = list->next;
  list->next = tail;

  return reverse_aux(tmp, list);
}

S* reverse(S* list) { return reverse_aux(list, NULL); }

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  // build a list with which to test
  S a[10];
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(S); ++i) {
    a[i].data = i;
    a[i].next = &a[i+1];
  }
  a[sizeof(a)/sizeof(S) - 1].next = NULL;
  S* list = &a[0];

  print_list(list);
  list = reverse(list);
  print_list(list);

  return 0;
}
```

Actually, since reverse is destructive (it mutates its argument), a better interface design would probably be

```
void reverse(S** plist);
reverse(&list);
```

Answer (score 0):

So there's two ways to reverse a list in place recursively.

First, some setup.  Let's make it easy to load linked lists
of strings and print them, so we can make sure this stuff works:

```
// linked_list.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// a linked lis of strings
typedef struct S {
  struct S * next;
  char * val;
} S;

// print out the list
void showS(char * const name, S * head) {
  printf("%s: (", name);
  while (head){
    printf(" ");
    printf("%s",head->val);
    head = head->next;
    printf( "%c", head ? ',' : ' ' );
  }
  printf(")\n");
}

// convert an array of strings into a linked list of strings
S * mkS(int n, char ** args) {
  S * head = NULL;

  if (n > 0 && (head = calloc(n, sizeof(S)))){
    S * curr = head - 1;

    while (n-- > 0) {
      curr++;
      curr->val = *args++;
      curr->next = curr + 1;
    }
    curr->next = NULL;
  }

  return head;
}
```

One way of reversing the list involves passing back the new head of the
list once we find it.  We don't need it locally (since we're just moving
the current element to the new end), but we'll need it so that the caller
has a pointer to the head of the list once we're done.

```
// reverse a list one way
S * revS1( S * const head ){
  if (head && head->next) {
    S * const new_head = revS1( head->next );
    head->next->next = head;
    head->next = NULL;
    return new_head;
  } else {
    return head;
  }
}
```

Another way takes a pointer to a pointer. The only difference is that
we don't need to return anything, since we're directly modifying a variable
the caller has.  I prefer this calling method since it's much clearer
that we're modifying the list, not returning a copy. It's also harder
for the caller to accidentally loose the pointer to the new head this way.

```
// reverse a list another way
void revS2( S ** phead ){
  S * const head = *phead;
  if (head && head->next) {
    *phead = head->next;
    revS2( phead );
    head->next->next = head;
    head->next = NULL;
  }
}
```

But what's better than either of these is to reverse the list non-recursively.
Neither of those functions is tail-recursive, so the compiler has
to allocate new stack frames for each element in the list. Try to reverse a long
enough list, and you'll blow your stack.  Much better to just reverse the list
using a while loop.

```
// reverse a list non-recursively
void revS3( S ** phead ){
  S * head = *phead;
  S * reversed = NULL;

  while (head) {
    S * curr = head;
    head = curr->next;
    curr->next = reversed;
    reversed = curr;
  }
  *phead = reversed;
}
```

Now we can test our results just by building lists out of the command line:

```
// just use the command line arguments as our list
int main(int argc, char** argv){

  S* list1 = mkS(argc - 1, argv + 1);
  S* list2 = mkS(argc - 1, argv + 1);
  S* list3 = mkS(argc - 1, argv + 1);

  showS( "given", list1 );

  showS( "revS1", revS1(list1) );

  revS2( &list2 );
  showS( "revS2", list2 );

  revS2( &list3 );
  showS( "revS3", list3 );

  return 0;
}
```

So let's compile:

```
% gcc -Wall linked_list.c -o linked_list
```

And do some test runs

```
% ./linked_list 
given: ()
revS1: ()
revS2: ()
revS3: ()
% ./linked_list first second third 
given: ( first, second, third )
revS1: ( third, second, first )
revS2: ( third, second, first )
revS3: ( third, second, first )
% ./linked_list only
given: ( only )
revS1: ( only )
revS2: ( only )
revS3: ( only )
```